# How to use for loop value in variable name

Tags: python

I'm trying to create multiple user with a for loop. In the code I want the "i" in Useri to be replaced by the value of i so that I can create User1, User2 and so on.

```
for i in range(x,y):
    Useri="Joy Smith"
```

Comment: `User1`, `User2`, `User3` or `Joy Smith`?

Comment: why not create a list of users?

Answer (score 0):

You should opt to create a `list` of users:

```
userList = []          # empty list
for i in range(1,6):   # iterate over a range
    userList.append("User" + str(i))   # append the users into the list

print(userList)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4', 'User5']
```

EDIT:

If you want the `Users` to have a name then you my create a `list` of perhaps, `names` as well.

```
userList = []
name = ['Joy Smith', 'Oliver Kahn', 'Alex Jay', 'Emkay Kay', 'Alexa Smith', 'Nitro Cage']

for i in range(1,len(name)):
    userList.append("User" + str(i) + ": " + name[i])
print(userList)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['User1: Oliver Kahn', 'User2: Alex Jay', 'User3: Emkay Kay', 
 'User4: Alexa Smith', 'User5: Nitro Cage']
```